# How does newOutputStream method work in JAVA?

Tags: java

While watching the package jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileSystem class

```
final OutputStream newOutputStream(JrtPath jrtPath, OpenOption... options) throws IOException {
     throw readOnly();
}
```

How does this function work when there is no return value?

I wonder what the principle of operation is.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XJkx.png)

Comment: Also see, [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: it is throwing an Exception, so the method terminates abruptly (with reason being that Exception) and nothing can be returned (that FileSystem apparently is read-only, so that operation is not permitted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`readOnly`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk20/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/jrtfs/JrtFileSystem.java#L256) is a static method in the same class.

```
static ReadOnlyFileSystemException readOnly() {
    return new ReadOnlyFileSystemException();
}
```

Hence `throw readOnly()` is equivalent to `throw new ReadOnlyFileSystemException()` as `readOnly` method returns an instance of `Exception`.

Comment: thank you I thought there was another device I didn't know about.